# Python / Conditionally replace a dataframe column given comparison to columns from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a df1 looking like this:

| old code | new code | date | material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a10 | a11 | 01.01.2010 | mat1 |
| a10 | a11 | 01.01.2010 | mat2 |
| b10 | b11 | 01.01.2011 | mat1 |

and another df2 looking like this:

| code | date | material |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a10 | 01.01.2008 | mat1 |
| a10 | 01.01.2007 | mat2 |
| a10 | 01.01.2012 | mat2 |
| b10 | 01.01.2005 | mat1 |

what is the most optimum way to replace only the code in df2 dataframe with the new code from df1 dataframe given the following conditions:
df1['old code']==df2['code'] and df2['date']<=df1['date'] and df1['material'] == df2['material']

in the example above the desired new df would be the following:

| code | date | material |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a11 | 01.01.2008 | mat1 |
| a11 | 01.01.2007 | mat2 |
| a10 | 01.01.2012 | mat2 |
| b11 | 01.01.2005 | mat1 |

So all records were updated apart from record in third row as the date criterion was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the dataframes on `code` and `materials` then test for the condition where date in df1 >= date in df2 then use boolean indexing with `loc` to update the values in `code` column where the condition is True

```
# Convert the columns to datetime
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], dayfirst=True)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], dayfirst=True)

df3 = df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'old code': 'code'}), 
                on=['code', 'material'], suffixes=['', '_r'], how='left')

df3.loc[df3.pop('date_r') >= df2['date'], 'code'] = df3.pop('new code')
```

Result

```
print(df3)

  code       date material
0  a11 2008-01-01     mat1
1  a11 2007-01-01     mat2
2  a10 2012-01-01     mat2
3  b11 2005-01-01     mat1
```